# Bringing specific items back from an array in a drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I currently have a standard registration form. In this form I have a drop down menu to select which type of school you are. I specially only want 2 out of the 5 items that appear in the drop down menu. What is the best way of approaching this? I am able to see all 5 options in the drop down menu. But only want the 2nd and 3rd to show.

I have an array of 5 objects. "item": [ {"id": 1,"name": "Company"}{"id":2,"name": "School District"},{"id": 3,"name": "High School"},{"id": 4,"name": "Community College"},{ "id": 5,"name": "Non Profit"}],

```
onCombinedSuccess = response => {
 this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    schoolTypes: response.item.schoolTypes.map(this.mapSchoolTypes),
    )
    };
   });
  };

 mapSchoolTypes = type => (
  <option key={type.id} value={type.id}>
  {type.name}
  </option>
   );
```

I only want Id 2: "School District, and Id 3 " High School" to show. Currently getting back all 5

Comment: `schoolTypes: response.item.schoolTypes.map(this.mapSchoolTypes).filter (item => (your logic to filter valid values)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```js
const items = [{"id": 1, "name": "Company"}, {"id": 2, "name": "School District"}, {"id": 3, "name": "High School"}, {"id": 4, "name": "Community College"}, {"id": 5,"name": "Non Profit"}];
const arrIDToSelect = [2, 3];
const arrFilteredItems = items.filter(item => arrIDToSelect.includes(item.id));

console.log(arrFilteredItems)
```